# How to fix up broken syntax in gitolite.conf pushed to origin

Tags: git, gitolite

I've added section for wildcards repos in gitolite.conf on my local clone of gitolite-admin.git repo

but i suddenly pushed commit with broken regex in repo name:

```
repo private/CREATOR/[A-z0-9_-+]
```

now gitolite claims that this regex is invalid, i've tryed:

```
git reset HEAD^1 --hard
git push --force
```

but this not helps, gitolite still claims about broken regex :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found answer, gl-dont-panic script witch comes with gitolite installation has solved the issue